# Mysql + Combobox

Tags: java, mysql, combobox

Hola alguien podria resolver mi problema..
Tengo un combobox cargado desde mysql con una tabla llamada estados lo que pretendo hacer es obtener la cantidad de ciudades que hay en el item seleccionado del combobox.

```
Select nombreciudad,count(nombreciudad) as Cantidad from estados group by nombreciudad order by Cantidad where nombrestado=;" +(item de combobox)
```

Comment: Que tal, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te recomiendo que leas lo siguiente para poder ayudarte con tu problema. https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/127226
Saludos.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, es importante revisar [ask] para que tengas idea de como crear preguntas en el sitio y puedas obtener la ayuda requerida, te recomendamos agregar lo que has tratado o investigado, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno lo primero que tendrías que hacer es que tu combobox cargue la consulta de la base de datos para que te despliegue la lista de estados, y ya que esta cargada esta información, seleccionas un "Estado" y deberás consultar a la base de datos que ciudades están relacionadas con el estado seleccionado con el siguiente código puedes "escuchar" el id o el valor que este relacionado al estado que te permita cargar la consulta de las ciudades....

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button#recargarCiudad").click(function(e){
         $("#Estado").on('change', function(){
            $("#Estado option:selected").each(function(){
                var cadenaClave = $('#Estado').val();
               
                $.ajax({
                async:true,
                cache:false,
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'cargarCiudades.php',data{cadenaClave:cadenaClave}
            })
        .done(function(data){
        $('#Ciudades').html(data);
        
        })
        .fail(function(){
        alert('Hubo un error al cargar la lista de ciudades');
            }); 
           });// fin de  each - función que escucha elemento-
        });
    });
   
});
```

Este script lo que hace es obtener un valor que podría ser un id o cualquier otro dato que te sirva para poder hacer la consulta a la bd y te regrese las ciudades que pertenecen al estado seleccionado...  o en su defecto que es para lo que yo lo uso, cargar un segundo selector dependiente del otro, ya teniendo estos datos los cuentas con Count y obtienes el numero de registros que te regresa.